# Magento 2.2 Open Source restrictions on each setting

Tags: magento2

1. When using **Magento 2.2** Open Source, is there a limit on the number of **websites** we can have?
2. Is there a limit on the number of **SKU**, **attribute set**, and attributes in **Mgaento 2.2** Open Source?
3. When setting **permissions** with **Magento 2.2** Open Source, can I select and set permissions on the website and store?
4. Insert a **full page cache** to improve page speed.
   For example, on one page, we want to just clear the cache from one part of the page.
   I would like to make improvements to adapt the cache on a per-block basis.
5. Currently in one magento, we have 4 Web sites | **Store view**. We use 3 sites for each (Japanese, English, Chinese).
   Default is regarded as a mall, and each is shared to each individual Website and Default URL.
   Now we have 4 stores, in the future we want to add in more sites, to around 20 to 30 more.
6. We would like to introduce **POS system** in which inventory information, product information, order information, customer information, point information, coupon information are linked fully with magento. Do you have an **ERP** or **POS system** compatible with **Magento 2.2** Open Source?
7. Every day, there is work such as creating a detailed page of products that arrives and publishing, the person in charge then makes preparation for publication.

   As we have more items piling up, the chances of human error gets higher, like forgetting to publish pages.
   Does Magento 2.2 Commerce have a function to dynamically set the schedule for publishing?
   is there a setting to publish the items with a time and date setting?
8. Everyday, as products are selling, we have to manually change and rearrange the items associated with the category.

   Example / 1) When there are items out of stock, we move the item to the bottom of the category page.

   ---

   Example / 2) When the attribute (season) associated with the product is new, we have to rearrange the item to be displayed on the top.

   We sort the products associated with the category according to various conditions.
   When rearranging products associated with categories, priorities are decided on the management screen, is there such a setting?
9. We currently sell products in e-commerce with 3 offline stores in Japan.
   Sometimes its open to just the store front.
   There are times a customer wants to come to our storefront to purchase something but wants to check the item on our EC site first and or see where and how many stocks are left.
   As we have 3 shops, when creating the product page, is there a setting that can show where and how many stocks is left and at which shop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In magento  or any other eCommerce there is always first concern about performance ( in term of load, speed and extend-ability ) then 2nd part comes to your question :

However I will try to answer to your each point , since your question is about setting limitation and i believe your comparison is between Magento Opensource ( Magento CE ) and Magento Commerce ( Magento EE ).

1 - There is no limit that how many websites you want to have you can have as many as you want.

2 - No there is not any limitations on SKUs, attribute sets and attributes, you can manage your site with more then 150k SKUs.

3 - in open source you can have different website admins, but can't on store levels. However if you have single admin for multiple sites then you don't have any built-in / default option to have permissions on website levels, you have to customize that.

4 - You can have integrated page cache-mechanism ( i.e Varnish etc ), but for that you have to customize / create VLC as per your requirements to which part / page should be cached and which should be left out.

5 - refer to point 1, you can have multiple sites / stores.

6 - yes you can integrate different POS with it, and that is nothing to do with Magento compatibility because that is always a different project. But it depends on the POS / ERP you are using and how much flexibility it gives.

This answer only covers limitations, not performance, since performance always depends on number of sites, skus, categories, stores and DB being used to manage / store all load of data, either you are going to use split db or one dedicated and blah blah... ).

Hope i cover all points you have mentioned.

**Additional Questions / Points Answers :**

7 - No there is not certain functionality available in both Magento Commerce and Magento Opensource , but you can have a custom module which will do that.

8 - For this you have to have custom module which do sorting for you, ( out of stock, new products, sort by qty etc ) currently have a project which have almost same requirements for sorting. Which i will be working.

9 - This is called omini-channel ( which is also supported by Magento commerce but have to mention specifically called "OMS" ), however this can be done in Magento opensource too. But that needs first integration with ERP / POS first then you can implement omni-channel thing.

Comment: Hi, Naveed
I have additional questions.
Could you please answer?
Thank you.

Comment: sure, what is that ?

Comment: Could you also please answer questions from 7 to 9 pleasse?

Comment: I have updated answer, if there is anything else feel free to message. I have gone through these things before and have worked with Magento Opensource, Magento commerce and Magento commerce cloud. I will be happy to assist and guide.

Comment: I thank you for your answer.

The question I want to do is all this.
However, I can not ask another question nearby.
First, another post near another.
In that case, I would be pleased if you answered.

Comment: sure no problem